# How do I call model.predict with data stored in GPU in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, keras

I have built and trained a Sequential model.

Now before each model.predict call I want to upload the data into GPU, do some operations and then call model.predict using the output stored in GPU without downloading to memory and handover to keras model for it to upload to gpu again.

Edit:
I would like to use opencv operations on the input image in gpu and use the output directly to call model.predict if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by adding the operations as `Lambda` layers on the top of the model.

Here is a very simple example.. you can extend from here:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, Input, merge

X = np.random.random((1000,5))
Y = np.random.random((1000,1))

inp = Input(shape = (5,))
d1 = Dense(60, input_dim=5, init='normal', activation='relu')
d2 = Dense(1, init='normal', activation='sigmoid')
out = d2(d1(inp))

model = Model(input=[inp], output=[out])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.summary()
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=1)



X1 = np.random.random((10,3))
X2 = np.random.random((10,2))

inp1 = Input(shape = (3,))
inp2 = Input(shape = (2,))

p1 = Lambda(lambda x: K.sqrt(x))(inp1)
p2 = Lambda(lambda x: K.tf.exp(x))(inp2)
mer = merge([p1, p2], mode='concat')
out2 = d2(d1(mer))

model2 = Model(input=[inp1, inp2], output=[out2])
model2.summary()

ypred = model2.predict([X1, X2])
print ypred.shape
```

Here from `model.summary()` you can see both the models are sharing the upper layers so in essence is using the weights already learnt during the training of the first model